# A solution of the ODE $\theta''(t)+\sin(\theta)=0$ with $\theta(0)=0$ is an odd function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the equation
>   $$\theta''(t)+\sin(\theta)=0, \theta(0)=0,\theta'(0)=\alpha>0$$
>   Prove that $\theta(t)=-\theta(-t)$ for every $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

It's a homework problem. 
I have shown that $\theta'^2=2\cos(\theta)-2+\alpha^2$, but I don't know that whether I can derive the result from this equation.

Comment: Define $\psi(t) = -\theta(-t)$, show that $\psi$ also solves the same IVP, and conclude by uniqueness.

Comment: Same idea: show $t \mapsto \phi(t)+\phi(-t)$ satisfies the equation and is identically zero.